# Prolog freezes when I check if a number variable is greater than another

Tags: prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog and I'm trying to solve the game light up

I have a predicate that check if there is more than one light in a row or a column

here is my code

```
lightenRow(I,J,R):-neighbor_row(I,J,RowN),count_lamp(RowN,R1),R is R1.
lightenCol(I,J,R):-neighbor_col(I,J,ColN),count_lamp(ColN,R1),R is R1.
isLighten(I,J):-lightenRow(I,J,R1),lightenCol(I,J,R2),R is R1+R2,R > 0.
```

`lightenRow` predicate uses `neighbor_row` predicate to get the neighbors of a cell
then I get the lamps number with the `count_lamp` predicate
I tried writing the result `R1` and `R2` and it's working fine

but when I add `R > 0`
it freezes and does not show any output when I call `isLighten`

what I want is to get true if `R` is greater than 0

Edit: here is my full code

```
:- dynamic rows/1.
:- dynamic cols/1.
:- dynamic wall/2.
:- dynamic cell/2.
:- dynamic wall_num/2.
:- dynamic light/2.

size(N,M):-
   integer(N),integer(M),assert(rows(N)),assert(cols(M)).
clear_board():-
   retractall(rows(_)),retractall(cols(_)).

rows_count(N):-rows(X),N is X.
cols_count(M):-cols(X),M is X.

inside(I,J):-rows_count(Rows),cols_count(Cols),I=<Rows,I>=1,J=<Cols,J>=1.

add_wall(I,J):-inside(I,J),assert(wall(I,J)).
add_wall_num(I,J,Value):-inside(I,J),assert(wall_num(I,J,Value)).
add_light(I,J):-inside(I,J),assert(light(I,J)).

add_cell_to_list(I,J,Cells,NewCells):-
   inside(I,J),
   TempList=[cell(I,J)],append(TempList,Cells,Result),NewCells=Result
;  append([],Cells,Result2),NewCells=Result2.

neighbor(I,J,Neighbors):-
   Left is J-1, Right is J+1, Top is I-1,Bottom is I+1,
   add_cell_to_list(I,Left,[],N1),
   add_cell_to_list(I,Right,N1,N2),
   add_cell_to_list(Top,J,N2,N3),
   add_cell_to_list(Bottom,J,N3,N4),
   Neighbors=N4.

neighbor_left(I,J,[]):-wall(I,J);wall_num(I,J,_);not(inside(I,J)).
neighbor_left(I,J,List):-
   NJ is J-1,
   neighbor_left(I,NJ,Rest),
   Temp=[cell(I,J)],
   append(Temp,Rest,Result),List=Result.

neighbor_right(I,J,[]):-wall(I,J);wall_num(I,J,_);not(inside(I,J)).
neighbor_right(I,J,List):-
   NJ is J+1,
   neighbor_right(I,NJ,Rest),
   Temp=[cell(I,J)],
   append(Temp,Rest,Result),List=Result.

neighbor_row(I,J,List):-
   LJ is J-1,
   neighbor_left(I,LJ,Result1),
   neighbor_right(I,J,Result2),
   append(Result1,Result2,Result),
   List=Result.

neighbor_up(I,J,[]):-wall(I,J);wall_num(I,J,_);not(inside(I,J)).
neighbor_up(I,J,List):-
   NI is I-1,
   neighbor_up(NI,J,Rest),
   Temp=[cell(I,J)],
   append(Temp,Rest,Result),
   List=Result.

neighbor_down(I,J,[]):-wall(I,J);wall_num(I,J,_);not(inside(I,J)).
neighbor_down(I,J,List):-
   NI is I+1,
   neighbor_down(NI,J,Rest),
   Temp=[cell(I,J)],
   append(Temp,Rest,Result),
   List=Result.

neighbor_col(I,J,List):-
   UI is I-1,
   neighbor_up(UI,J,Result1),
   neighbor_down(I,J,Result2),
   append(Result1,Result2,Result),
   List=Result.

isLight(I,J):-light(I,J).

count_lamp([],0).
count_lamp([cell(I,J)|Rest],Result):-
   isLight(I,J),count_lamp(Rest,Result2),Result is Result2+1.
count_lamp([cell(I,J)|Rest],Result):-
   not(isLight(I,J)),count_lamp(Rest,Result2),Result is Result2.

lightenRow(I,J,R):-neighbor_row(I,J,RowN),count_lamp(RowN,R1),R is R1.
lightenCol(I,J,R):-neighbor_col(I,J,ColN),count_lamp(ColN,R1),R is R1.
isLighten(I,J):-lightenRow(I,J,R1),lightenCol(I,J,R2),R is R1+R2,R > 0.
```

Comment: The code you posted does not compile : `ERROR: neighbor_left/3: Undefined procedure: wall_num/3`

Comment: I don't think the comparison to zero is to blame here. I tried the three lines of codes you initially posted by mocking the unknown functions with integers values and it worked perfectly.

Comment: it works when I use any other procedure 
the error in wall_num/3 , wall/2 ,light/2 that it's not declare in the code 
it's add during run time with 'assert' in add_wall/2 add_wall_num/3 add_light/2

Comment: Did you try doing a `trace` to see what your code is doing? What have you tried in order to debug this? Just an aside, `Temp=[cell(I,J)],
   append(Temp,Rest,Result), List=Result.` can be written simply as, `List = [cell(I,J) | Rest]`. And as @meucaa says, you have syntax errors in this code. For example, `clear_board() :-` isn't valid Prolog syntax. If you really did get some results, please post the code you actually tried.

Comment: What query did you run?